# jQuery set active class for button select

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, radio-button

I have some html stuffs like this,

```
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Low Cost/Effeciency</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">Average</button>
</div>
<div class="btn-group" role="group">
    <button type="button" class="btn btn-default">High Cost</button>
</div>
```

From my above snippets, each `btn-group` contains one `button`. I want to add `active` class when `button` click and remove `active` class which is the button already set as `active`. It means like radio button selection.

I tried like this in jQuery, but doesn't provide exact solutions.

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-group button', function (e) {
    $(this).addClass('active').parent('.btn-group').find('button').removeClass('active');
});
```

How can I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`toggleClass`](http://api.jquery.com/toggleclass/) for doing that,

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-group button', function (e) {
    $(this).toggleClass('active');
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vuzvvq27/)

***Edit:***

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn-group button', function (e) {
    $(".active").not($(this).addClass('active')).removeClass();
});
```

### [DEMO](https://jsfiddle.net/vuzvvq27/1/)

Comment: Thanks for your immediate response. This is partially works well like multiple `active` selections. But I want to only one `active` class at a time like radio button selection.

Comment: @Ranjith Edit panniten. Ithu tha ninga expect panna result ah?

Comment: It works perfectly. Thanks Rajaprabhu. Tamilan always mastermind :)

Comment: What does "Edit panniten. Ithu tha ninga expect panna result ah" mean?

Comment: @evolutionxbox Sorry I shouldn't used my local language here. I asked, "I have done an edit. Is this what you have expected as a result?"

Answer (score 0):

Try below:

```
$(document).on('click', '.btn', function (e) {
   $(".btn").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active")
});
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

`$(document).on('click', '.btn.btn-default', function (e) {
   $(".btn.btn-default").removeClass("active");
   $(this).addClass("active");
});`